# PHP auto-submit form if Input text box is empty

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to submit the form so that the data on my page gets refreshed. This works fine if I submit the form (empty or not) manually. I want to submit the form **automatically** if the textbox is ***EMPTY***. I do not want the form to be submitted if the person is **typing**. But for some reason, this is not working.

My Form:

```
<form  action=thispage.php method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Your Message here" width="100" id="cm" onblur="refresh(this)">
 <input type="submit" value="Send"  id="snd">
</form>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
  function refresh(field){
   if (field.value==''){
     document.getElementById('snd').click();

   }
  }
  setInterval(refresh,1000);
</script>
```

The Above code does not submit my form ***AT ALL***.
So I tried another option:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
  function refresh(){ 
  //this time without any argument and no function handling in the input textbox
    if (document.getElementById('cm').value=""){
      document.getElementById('snd').click();
    }
  }
  setInterval(refresh,1000);
</script>
```

But in this case, the form gets submitted *EVERY* 1  second, **even if the user is *TYPING***.

Comment: This is your culprit `setInterval(refresh,1000);`

Comment: Condition is wrong in your javascript code : below is the correct code

`if (document.getElementById('cm').value===""){`

Comment: `document.getElementById('cm').value=""` is _setting_ the field value, not comparing it. Use `==` or even better `===`.

Comment: Even if you sort this out (eg so it doesnt constantly submit before the user has started to type). it is going to suck ui wise. A refresh can be slow on poor connections, it may reset the scroll position etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the 1st place, there is certainly a better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have issue with condtion use `==` or `===` instead of `=` for comparision

```
<script>
  function refresh(){ 

  //this time without any argument and no function handling in the input textbox
    if (document.getElementById('cm').value==""){
      document.getElementById('snd').click();
    }
  }
  setInterval(refresh,1000);
</script>
```

Comment: So close as typo instead of answering

Comment: great, so user loads page, reads a few lines of text and bang, the page reloads.

Comment: @Steve no man, if u used some of your brain, you would have known that, the page will submit the form (not reload) ONLY when user is not typing.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your question is incorrect. If input text if empty then why you are going to submit. It should be if the input text is not empty then submit the form. @Mrigank

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh(obj){ 
            var val = obj.value;
            if (val.trim()!=""){
                alert("Form is Submitted.");
                document.getElementById('snd').click();
            }
    }
    </script>
```

You can add autofocus attribute in input type text so after refresh, it will automatically focus on the text field.

```
    <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Type Your Message here" onblur="refresh(this)" autofocus>
```

For Demo Checkout:  [Demo](http://blog.prakhar.info/submit-form-automatically-text-field-not-empty/)

Comment: Sorry man, u got it all wrong. My question is COMPLETELY correct, it was just a typo. Just do some research, you will understand.

Comment: Ok, that means you have to secure it from debug console.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! the second code is doing the Job. Just modify (.value = "") to (.value === "")

```
function refresh() {
    console.log(document.getElementById('cm').value)
    console.log('refresh')
    //this time without any argument and no function handling in the 
input textbox
    if (document.getElementById('cm').value === "") {
        document.getElementById('snd').click();
    }
}
setInterval(refresh, 1000);
```